# Downloading Web Page with Download Manager

Tags: java, android, native, android-download-manager, httpconnection

I am Using Download Manager for Downloading Webpage URLS, which may have extension .txt/.pdf...Some Http Links like "www.abc.com" cant be opened once downloaded

The Following is the code I tried

```
DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        uRl = uRl.replace("https://", "http://");
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                                | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE).setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(true).setTitle("Files - " + "Downloading.. " + uRl)
                .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
                .setMimeType(getMimeType(uRl))
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "FilesFromApp/" + getFileName(uRl));
        downloadId = mgr.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: `replace("https://", "http://");` That is nonsense. Please remove.

Comment: `"www.abc.com" cant be opened once downloaded` Why not? What did you get?      What is the problem?  `getFileName(uRl))` Tel us the name.